# Error: uncaught exception: [Exception..."String contains an...."

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, dom

I am running the following javascript:

```
$('img').each(
    function(){
        var w = parseInt(this.width);
            alert(w);
            alert(this.src);
        if(w > 300){

            var percent = parseInt((w/666)*100);
            $(this).removeAttr('width height').css('width',percent + "%");

        }
});
```

And I am getting the following error:

> Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "String contains an invalid
>   character"  code: "5" nsresult: "0x80530005
>   (NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR)"  location:
>   "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js Line: 2"]

I'm having trouble actually trying to track this one down as it isn't very descriptive of the problem or the source of the problem. Can anyone shed some light on the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using escaped quotes? Use `$('img').each(/*...*/);`

Comment: Are the escapes (\\) in your actual code?

Comment: That's a pretty accurate error code :) -- `String contains an invalid character`.

Comment: This is a lot of code for a simple bug. I would recommend trying to narrow down where in the code the problem occurs by removing lines until you find the one that it is on. Might even find the solution yourself before having to post it :)

Comment: stupid me, ignore the escapes, thats because they are in a php string. They aren't actually done when the document is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't know the proper syntax.
Try this:

```
$('img').each(
    function(){
        var w = parseInt(this.width);
            alert(w);
            alert(this.src);
        if(w > 300){

            var percent = parseInt((w/666)*100);
            $(this).removeAttr('width height').css('width',percent + "px");

        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(\'img\')` won't work. Should be `$('img')`. There's a few other places where you are trying to escape the single quotes, but you don't need to. Your code should look more like this:

```
$('img').each(
    function(){
        var w = parseInt(this.width);
            alert(w);
            alert(this.src);
        if(w > 300){

            var percent = parseInt((w/666)*100);
            $(this).removeAttr('width height').css('width',percent + "px");

        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it [is *running* perfectly](http://jsfiddle.net/XagJr/1/) for me -- although it does not change the size the images -- so the problem is probably somewhere else in your code/page.

On the logic in the code, i am however unsure about what you are trying to do here;

```
parseInt((W/666)*100)
```

Are you trying to get all the pictures to be a width max size?  i.e. downscaling the picture in the browser?   [If so, why not just set the size to a fixed value](http://jsfiddle.net/XagJr/2/), like;

```
$('img').each(
    function(){
        var maxwidth = 300;
        var w = parseInt(this.width);
        var h = parseInt(this.height)
        if(w > maxwidth){
            var hscale = parseInt(h/(w/maxwidth));
            $(this).width(maxwidth).height(hscale);
        }
});
```